# Android GridView - How to change a bitmap dynamically?

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, bitmapsource

Hello I have a gridView which I use to show some pictures on (small thumb of diffrent levels).
When the user finishes one level, I would like to change the thumb for that level. (Somehow show that it has been completed).

I created two thumbs for each level. One is the original and one that shows that the level is completed.

But how can i change the source of the images?

The code which I use to draw the images looks like this.

The main activity:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);

  GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
  gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Open the map which was clicked on, if there is one
        if(position+1 > 1){
            Toast.makeText(maps.this, "Level " + (position+1) + " is not yet available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(maps.this, "Opening Level " + (position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Tutorial2D.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
      }
  });
}
```

The ImageAdapter Class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    //Changing
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}



// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.map1, R.drawable.map2, R.drawable.map3,
        R.drawable.map4, R.drawable.map5, R.drawable.map6,
        R.drawable.map7, R.drawable.map8, R.drawable.map9,
        R.drawable.map10, R.drawable.map11, R.drawable.map12,
        R.drawable.map13, R.drawable.map14, R.drawable.map15,
        R.drawable.map16, R.drawable.map17, R.drawable.map18,
        R.drawable.map19
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new bitmap based off a thumb and draw your extra graphics over it using a canvas. Then you could pass that bitmap to the imageview using imageView.setImageBitmap

[edit]

something like

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    if (mLevelfinished) {

        //create thumbnail bitmap
        mThumbBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, mThumbIds[position]);

        //draw a check over the bitmap
        Canvas c = new Canvas(mThumbBmp);
        c.drawBitmap(mCheckBitmap, destX, destY, null);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbBmp);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

[edit2]

I now see I kinda misunderstood your question.. doh. Instead of creating the level complete thumb dynamically, you already have thumbs for those. In that case, I would create another array that has those completed thumbs and pick the resource from the correct array. And to stick with arrays, maybe store the level completion in one as well:

```
imageView.setImageResource((mLevelCompleted[position]) ? mThumbCompleteIds[position] : mThumbIds[position]);
```

Comment: Will could you be little more precise? Do you have a sample code I could look at? I don´t understand why I should create a Canvas to do the image manipulation in?

Comment: I update my answer with some code. To manipulate a Bitmap you'll need a Canvas object.

Comment: Hi Will, yeah it works. I saved some missionCompletedVariables in a SharedPreference and created the picture I needed from right array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(Punch.this, "" + mThumbIds[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     mThumbIds[position]=R.drawable.crabx;//crabxImg;

  //here is where I would like to redraw the whole grid but it will not let me. 
  //Because ImageAdapter is not defined within this callback.
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a dirty trick that might be useful when you know previously what bitmaps will be shown.

I set up another invisible `ImageView` just aside the visible one, and manipulate

```
myImageView.setVisibility(n); // (n = 0 = View.VISIBLE) or (n = 8 = View.GONE)
```

Do not use the constant `View.INVISIBLE` which values `4`, because `View.GONE` is the right effect. When the visibility is set to `View.GONE`, the object will not take space in the layout. This is similar to `display: none;` from CSS.